# CodingBat Warmup-1 near_hundred Python

Tags: python

The prompt is:

Given an int n, return True if it is within 10 of 100 or 200. Note: abs(num) computes the absolute value of a number.

ex. 
near_hundred(93) → True

near_hundred(90) → True

near_hundred(89) → False

I wanted code that could return a 'near hundred' value for any number so I used this technique:

```
def near_hundred(n):
  r = n % 100
  r = abs(r)

  return( r >= 90 or r <= 10)
```

The issue is for test values '0', '5', or '290' my program returns a false negative. What am I not understanding that causes this?

Comment: Consider calculating `abs(100-r)` and `abs(200-r)`.

Comment: Your code as written returns `True` if `n` is within 10 of any number divisible by 100, including zero also.

Comment: Can you show how you're calling it?  near_hundred(0) returns True for me

Comment: (Note that as Brian points out, zero is a multiple of a hundred; if you want to treat 0 or 9 as not being near 100, you would probably want to special case that), but near_hundred(290) does also return True [I'm interpretting false negative as meaning in your case, you're getting False]

Answer (score 3):

```
return (abs(100-n) <= 10) or (abs(200-n) <= 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution - Probably Not the most Efficient but is Readable**

```
def near_hundred(n):
  if 90 <= n <= 110:
    return True
  elif 190 <= n <= 210:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def near_hundred(n):
  if n in range (90, 111):
    return True
  elif n in range (190, 211):
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

It tests for n in the range 90 - 111 and 190 to 211 (Note range does not account for the last number, so 111 and 211 are not included).

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
def near_hundred(n):
  if n < 90 or (n > 110 and n<190):
    return False
  elif n>210:
    return False
  elif abs(100-n) >= 90 or 110<=(100+n) :
    return True 
  return False
```

Comment: There's no point to the final `elif`. It's mutually exclusive to your other two conditions already, so just use `else`. Less chance to introduce bugs. Also, I don't understand why you decided to use `or` on the first condition and then split the second one in its own branch.

Answer (score -1):

My solution:

```
def nearHundred(n):
    if 90 <= n <= 110 or 190 <= n <= 210:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (n>=90 and n<=110 or n>=190 and n<=210):
    return True
else:
    return False
```